# prestashop 1.6, css files isn't loaded in back-office

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

After charged project into server, css files isn't loaded in back-office,despite I emptied the cache, but in front-office all things is nice.

css files i need to load is admin-theme.css and overrides.css. they exist in
\admin-xxx\themes\default\css folder .

Comment: Try to regenerate .htaccess. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. PrestaShop was using an old admin directory, because I have done migration from 1.5 to 1.6. I've changed the name of this directory and now everything is ok.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is in changing the path to the CSS and JS.

Probably your problem is connected with .htaccess file.

1. Navigate to **Preferences** -> **SEO & URLs**.
2. Set **Friendly URL** option to **No** and click **Save** button.
3. Enable **Friendly URL** back and save the changes.
4. Now `.htaccess` should be successfully regenerated
5. Check your back office again.